# Method return type in Dimension class of java.awt

Tags: java, double, awt, dimension

I am surprised to see that getters of `height` and `width` members has `return` type `double`, albeit they are `int`. Moreover, `setSize` method with double parameters has the following definition:

```
/**
 * Sets the size of this <code>Dimension</code> object to
 * the specified width and height in double precision.
 * Note that if <code>width</code> or <code>height</code>
 * are larger than <code>Integer.MAX_VALUE</code>, they will
 * be reset to <code>Integer.MAX_VALUE</code>.
 *
 * @param width  the new width for the <code>Dimension</code> object
 * @param height the new height for the <code>Dimension</code> object
 */
public void setSize(double width, double height) {
    this.width = (int) Math.ceil(width);
    this.height = (int) Math.ceil(height);
}
```

Please have a look at [Dimension](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-5.0/java/awt/Dimension.java.html) class. Above comment says values cannot go beyond Integer.MAX_VALUE. Why?
Why do we have `double` in between? Is there any subtle reason? Can anyone please explain this to me? Sorry for my insistence!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.awt.Dimension` was retrofitted to fit into the `java.awt.geom` package, so that it can be used wherever a `Dimension2D` is required. The interface for the later deals with floating point, so `Dimension` has to also. Being limited to `int` fields, only a subset of `double`s can be represented. `Dimension2D.Float` is similarly restricted.

Answer (score 3):

The class is storing `height` and `width` as `int`, it just provides a method that accept double too so you can call it with double values (but they are immediately cast to int). There are others `setSize()` methods in this file that accept `int` values or even a `Dimension` object.

And as these values are stored as `int`, of course their maximum value is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Thats it? Why do we have getters with `double` as `return` type? Any use?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason why they return as double (probably because when talking about dimensions, you're talking about precision and double is more used in these cases), but for the setters, it is just some method overloading to help the user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't think `double`s having int values will help in precision. I mean double 1517.00 is equal to 1517, so there must be some reason?

Comment: @Ahamed no I know, what I meant was more that people are working with double values when working with dimensions, and they set the return type of getters to double so users don't have to cast it on their side. But I agree that in terms of precision there's no use.

Comment: @Ahamed I have to admit that it is interesting, good question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java Dimension class with ints. If you'd need a Dimension class with double width and height, youn could use the following:

```
public class DoubleDimension {
    double width, height;

    public DoubleDimension(double width, double height) {
        super();
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DoubleDimension [width=" + width + ", height=" + height + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(height);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(width);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DoubleDimension other = (DoubleDimension) obj;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(height) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.height))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(width) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.width))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also extend `Dimension2D` class so you keep compatibility with other Java functions. I implemented something similar in Kotlin  https://gist.github.com/vladostaci/db4f601611879aa657403ff277324130